# Adding a X509 certificate to the store in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, certificate

Under Windows XP and Vista I could use the CapiCOM dll to handle X509 certificates.
However this route has been deprecated under Window 7 (and later).

In the Delphi help (XE6) I can only find X509 code in Data.DBXCommon.TX509Certificate, but that does not look like it has anything to do with the Windows certificate store.

MSDN tells me to use `system.dll` and `system.security.dll`, but XE6 does not seem to be shipped with header files for these:

<sub>(Missing system.dll header files)</sub>
[image: No system/system.security header files included]

How to I translate the following code so that it works under Windows 7?

```
uses
  Capicom_TLB, CapicomConst, ActiveX;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CertificateFilename: PWideChar;
  Store: TStore;
  Certificate: ICertificate2;
  Password: WideString;
begin
  if FileOpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    CertificateFilename:= StringToOleStr(FileOpenDialog1.FileName);
    Store:= TStore.Create(Self);
    try
      Password:= '';
      Store.Open(CAPICOM_LOCAL_MACHINE_STORE, CAPICOM_ROOT_STORE, CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_READ_WRITE);
      Certificate:= TCertificate.Create(Self) as ICertificate2;
      Certificate.Load(CertificateFilename^, Password, CAPICOM_KEY_STORAGE_DEFAULT, CAPICOM_LOCAL_MACHINE_KEY);
      Store.Add(Certificate as ICertificate2);
    finally
      Store.Close;
      SysFreeString(CertificateFilename);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If I could get code that works from Windows XP up to Windows 8/9 that would be an bonus.

Answer (score 1):

The Crypto API is, according to my websearches, the unmanaged interface that you are looking for. I suspect that [`CryptUIWizImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380598.aspx) may be the easiest way to do what you need.

This article has some simple code demonstrating how to call the function: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/01/31/how-to-import-a-certificate-without-user-interaction-c-c.aspx

I have no personal experience of doing this so I may be wide of the mark.

Comment: From the description in the MSDN article it looks correct. Let me see if I can figure out in which dll this function lives.

Comment: It's in `CryptUI.dll`: `function CryptUIWizImport(dwFlags: DWORD; HWndParent: HWND; WizardTitle: PWideString;
  ImportSrc: PCCRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO; hDestCertStore: THandle): BOOL; stdcall; external 'CryptUI.dll';`

Comment: I tried using the CryptUI dll function, but the structs used are so insanely complex that that approach is simply not doable.  Will try a commandline approach instead.

Comment: That's entirely up to you